# Centralizar imagens lado a lado

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de centralizar estas duas imagens lado a lado, mas em tela pequena a de baixo fica muito junta da imagem de cima

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
/*This stylesheet sets the width of all images to 100%: */
img {
    width:100%;
}
</style>

</head>


<body>

</br>
</br>

<div align="center" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3"> <p>Moodle</p> <a href="/moodle"> <img src="http://educar.esy.es/img/if_Quiz-Games_190314.png" alt="Moodle" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></a> </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3"> <p>Relatórios</p> <a href="/moodle"> <img src="http://educar.esy.es/img/if_report_56294.png" alt="Relatórios" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></a> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tente utilizar um `pandding: auto` ou `margin: auto` no css da `div`, na `class:row`, nesse caso. Dependendo do comportamento das imagens.

Comment: Akashi, desculpe mas não sei como e onde declarar isso aí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o jeito fácil de resolver isso é colocando um margin-botton na imagem, assim vc não interfere criando classes no Grid do Bootstrap como na .row ou na col-

Veja como fica nesse exemplo:

```css
img {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<style>
/*This stylesheet sets the width of all images to 100%: */

</style>

</head>


<body>

</br>
</br>

<div align="center" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    <div class="col-md-3"> <p>Moodle</p> <a href="/moodle"> <img src="http://educar.esy.es/img/if_Quiz-Games_190314.png" alt="Moodle" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></a> </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3"> <p>Relatórios</p> <a href="/moodle"> <img src="http://educar.esy.es/img/if_report_56294.png" alt="Relatórios" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></a> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Resolveu valeu mesmo!

Comment: Miguel vi que vc está começando com CSS/Html então só uma observação, não use o estilo assim: `img {margin...}` Crie uma classe exclusiva para esse ocasião e use quando precisar, por exemplo `img.margemb {margin...}` e depois na imagem coloque `<img class="margemb">` Se vc não fizer assim todas suas imagem vão ter uma margem inclusive as que não precisam. Qq dúvida fala ai.

Comment: OK, Obrigado hugocsl